# Normal map stamps

Tags: normal-map

I saw a video a long time ago where someone was modelling a game asset in Blender and they used normal map stamps/decals to add small details like vents and bolt heads etc.

I remember they just stamped them on wherever they wanted and didn't have to mess around with creating planes and shrink wrapping them or positioning UVs in exact positions etc. I can't find the video now and really struggling to find any examples or tutorials on how to do this in a quick and easy way even just for a flat surface.

Is a third party plugin like DecalMachine the only way to do it?

*EDIT: Not even sure if DecalMachine does this actually? Looks like they have their own more complex system with their own materials etc and its not just stamping shapes into normal map*

Comment: is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beGiL2QchxY) what you're looking for?

Comment: @MartyFouts I did already find that but it seemed more complex than I remember in the video I saw before. I'm sure in the video I saw there was no positioning UVs or anything like that. It was just a case of stamping the normal onto the mesh like it was a brush (like you can do in Substance Painter). Maybe I am misremembering though, or maybe he was using DecalMachine or KitOps

Comment: I thought you'd probably already seen that and it was long shot to mention.  As far as I know, DecalMachine, which basically automates that technique is the only tool that automates doing the stamps with normal maps.   The other approach I'm familiar with is to create a stamp brush and use it in texture painting to stamp on a texture; but it works differently.

Comment: @MartyFouts yeah I tried using a custom brush in texture painting but it didn't work how I wanted at all really. I guess most people just either use DecalMachine or substance painter for this kind of thing then?